# Python's assert_called_with, is there a wildcard character?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, assert

Suppose I have a class in python set up like this.

```
from somewhere import sendmail

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.sendmail = kwargs.get("sendmail", sendmail)  #if we can't find it, use imported def

    def publish():

        #lots of irrelevant code
        #and then

        self.sendmail(mail_to, mail_from, subject, body, format= 'html')
```

So as you can see, I have sort of given myself the option to parameterize which function I use for self.sendmail

Now in the test file.

```
Class Tester():

    kwargs = {"sendmail": MagicMock(mail_from= None, mail_to= None, subject= None, body= None, format= None)}
    self.myclass = MyClass(**kwargs)

    ##later on
    def testDefaultEmailHeader():

        default_subject = "Hello World"
        self.myclass.publish()

        self.myclass.sendmail.assert_called()  #this is doing just fine
        self.myclass.sendmail.assert_called_with(default_subject)  #this is having issues
```

For some reason I am getting the error message

```
AssertionError: Expected call: mock('Hello World')
                Actual Call : mock('defaultmt', 'defaultmf', 'Hello World', 'default_body', format= 'html')
```

So basically, the assert is expecting sendmail to be called with only one variable, when it ends up being called with all 5. The thing is, I don't care about what the other 4 variables are! I just want to make sure it is called with the correct subject.

I tried the mock place holder ANY, and got the same thing

```
self.myclass.sendmail.assert_called_with(ANY, ANY, 'Hello World', ANY, ANY)

AssertionError: Expected call: mock(<ANY>, <ANY>, 'Hello World', <ANY>, <ANY>)
Actual Call : mock('defaultmt', 'defaultmf', 'Hello World', 'default_body, 'format= 'html')
```

Really unsure on how to proceed with this one. Anyone have any advice if we only care about one of the variable and want to ignore the rest?

Comment: Did you mean `format='html'` instead of `'format='html'`, latter is ambiguous? Try `self.myclass.sendmail.assert_called_with(ANY, ANY, 'Hello World', ANY, format=ANY)`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're calling `sendmail` with a named parameter `subject` then it's better to check whether the named argument matches what you expect:

```
args, kwargs = self.myclass.sendmail.call_args
self.assertEqual(kwargs['subject'], "Hello World")
```

This does assume both implementations of `sendmail` have a named parameter called `subject`. If that's not the case you can do the same with a positional parameter:

```
args, kwargs = self.myclass.sendmail.call_args
self.assertTrue("Hello World" in args)
```

You can be explicit about the position of the argument (i.e., the first argument or the third argument that's passed to `sendmail` but that depends on the implementation of `sendmail` being tested).

Comment: In the first example your MagicMock has five named parameters while you're passing one positional argument so it won't know that your argument is actually the third named parameter (subject). In the second example you're using the ANY placeholder but I haven't used that thus far.

Comment: This does not answer the question. In many cases (e.g. checking if a logger gets called, but not making the test verify a particular log message string), you need to check if a mock has been called, but you do not care (and may not know) with what arguments it has been called.

Comment: The question states that one argument is relevant for the test, it's not just about asserting any logging call.

Answer (score 24):

Using `ANY` from `unittest.mock`, wild cards are possible with `assert_called_with`:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY

self.myclass.sendmail.assert_called_with(
    subject="Hello World",
    mail_from=ANY,
    mail_to=ANY,
    body=ANY,
    format=ANY,
)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any

Comment: this answer was the cleaner solution for my issue. interesting that none of the libraries haven't implemented it..

Comment: Creative and pythonic

Comment: Great suggestion! Works perfectly when doing asserts of JSON/dicts, where some values are hard to determine (for example, some generated items IDs). I used this pattern to implement `AnyInt()` and `AnyISODate()` which made my Django/DRF unittest much cleaner.

Comment: `unittest.mock` supports `ANY` since at least Python 3.5, which implements `__eq__` identically to this answer. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any

Comment: Thanks @BrendanBatliner, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
args, _ = your_mock.call_args
assert "must-exist-string" in str(args)
```